# Does ng-init and ng-repeat bind properly?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-init

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="x in AList" data-ng-init="loopIndex=$index;">
<select data-ng-model='y.value' style="width:80%;margin-left:20px;" data-ng-change="filter()" data-ng-init="test123=x.name;">
<option data-ng-repeat="y in BList" value="{{y.test123}}">{{y.test123}}></option>
```

The above code has 2 arrays

`Alist` which has field name, the value of name is a field in `Blist`, lets suppose value of field name  in `Alist` is text.

When I directly write `y.text` instead of `y.test123`, the value populates on the screen and also in option value, but when I try to fetch the value in `test123` and then I write the above code, neither the value populates in option value nor it is displayed on the screen.

Comment: `test123` which you are accessing is not the property of `y`, so nothing is displayed.

Comment: if I print the variable test123 it gives me the values as text

Comment: how is y.text123 it different from writing y.text

Comment: `y` is an object, so when you execute `y.text123` it will assume that there is a property with the name `text123` inside `y`, which doesn't exists in your case (or show me the complete `y` object in the question). `y.text` and `y.text123` are considered as two different properties inside `y`.

Comment: can't we call a property of y using variable in angular?

Comment: lets assume y has properties like quoteid and company name.

Comment: text123 fetched both these values

Answer (score 0):

1. If you call y.test123 you should have a attribute inside the BLits array.

   ex: BLits = [test123:'sampletext']
2. data-ng-init="test123=x.name;" this code should work and if you use {{test123}} it will populate the x.name value.

so I assume you don't have a attribute called test123 inside BLits array and so it does not populate any value. instead it will give a error on your console.

Comment: I have understood this problem, but how we we resolve it?

Comment: test123 fetches the values of attributes of Y

Comment: what do you need to do? give the flow of what you want to do and I will help you.

Comment: see lets assume 
Alist has a field brand which has values like nokia,apple
Blist has fields like nokia and apple
I try to fetch nokia and apple using text123 from Alist
how can I write {{y.test123}} to fetch the value of y.nokia or y.apple
As Blist has many field so we need to dynamically fetch values

Comment: Am I able to explain my problem well?

Comment: yeah you want to filter from the name of Alist to Blist. Sorry I didn't notice the filter function. wait ill update my code

Answer (score 0):

the above problem can be solved if we simply write test123 in square brackets, accessing array of objects

```
y[test123]
```